# Karate: Why NullPointerException at FileUtils happens for mvn clean-integration-test?

Tags: karate

Our Karate Scripts for Integration Test works as expected when we use the cmd- mvn integration-test. if we use clean it fails with the below error and the successfully executed test not executing again.

**Error log given below when we use the cmd - mvn clean integration-test**

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.13:integration-test (default) @ formfill ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: D:\Baskaran\wvid-stash\formfill\target\failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.dnb.vici.formfill.it.FormFill_ITSuite
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.27 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(com.dnb.vici.formfill.it.FormFill_ITSuite)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.intuit.karate.FileUtils.resolveIfClassPath(FileUtils.java:157)
        at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateFeature.<init>(KarateFeature.java:47)
        at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateFeature.loadFeatures(KarateFeature.java:62)
        at com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate.<init>(Karate.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
```

**Our configuration in POM is given below for reference.**

```
    <!-- Following plugin executes the unit tests -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->                
    </plugin>

    <!-- Following plugin executes the integration tests -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/FormFill_ITSuite.java</include>
            </includes>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>                    
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you look at the sources of FileUtils, line 157? It looks like there is a problem with a Resource that's not being loaded? Maybe you should attach a debugger?

Comment: Thanks @Keulej. i looked that, I don't have any to load from resources folder apart from the logback configuration. Whenever the project imported again and run the mvn integration-test, it works as expected. Getting the issue only when i do mvn clean integration-test.

Comment: @BaskaranK which version of Karate is this. I'm sorry this is not enough info to replicate. I notice you are on windows and it is possible this is a bug. try to not use the integration test maven life cycle and stick to the Karate examples using JUnit. else you need to submit an issue with a working example if you want any confidence of us fixing this.

Comment: @PeterThomas, Thanks for your quick response :) I tried to use Karate as integration test for our Spring boot application using junit runner only. we have the unit test is in place using junit. Our intention is to execute both unit and integration test sequentially after every build. I will try to share the working example ASAP to replicate the same.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same NullPointerException when I compiled my tests with JDK 1.7.0_75. Using 1.8.0_72 instead worked.

You say your tests work before and they stop working when using 'mvn clean'. Unfortunately you don't tell us how you got them working in the first place. But 'mvn clean' removes the existing artifacts and if they are then compiled again with an older JDK, the NullPointerException occurs.